# How to do a POST with XML API?

Tags: php, xml, youtube-api

Here we see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments#Adding_a_comment

I need to do a request with XML API.

```
POST /feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <content>This is a crazy video.</content>
</entry>
```

What should I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to do this.

```
<?php
$data = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
    <content>This is a crazy video.</content>
</entry>
XML;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array('Content-Type: application/atom+xml',
    'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN',
    'GData-Version: 2',
    'X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY'));
$re = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely find it easiest to use one of the client libraries rather than do the POST manually, because it will handle header generation, authentication, and tokens for you without a lot of hassle. A list of the client libraries is here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/code

For example, to do a comment post with the Python client, it would look something like this (assuming you'd gone through the authentication steps, which the clients make pretty simple):

```
my_comment = 'what a boring test video'
video_id = '9g6buYJTt_g'
video_entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=video_id)
yt_service.AddComment(comment_text=my_comment, video_entry=video_entry)
```

The clients for other languages follow the same structure.

Comment: nice! thought i was gon have to go through xml hell!